# Vimのコマンドラインウインドウに表示されているメッセージをクリップボードにコピーしたい

Tags: vim

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ALE等のプラグインを使っていると、Linterがこのようなメッセージをコマンドラインウインドウに表示してくれますが、これをそのままクリップボードにコピーし、ブラウザでGoogle検索等を行いたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:messages` をバッファに出す方法を紹介します。

```
:new
:put =execute('messages')
```

これで新しいバッファに `:messages` の出力が書き込まれるので、通常のテキストと同様に扱えます。

ただし、中には `:messages` に記録されないメッセージもあります。その場合は表示された後で結果を取ることは残念ながらできません。(CUI なら端末側の機能で取ることはできます)

Answer (score 3):

[thinca](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/2541/thinca)さんの[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/40779/25936)を見ていて閃きました。
`:messages`の最下行をクリップボードへコピーするコマンドとクエリにしてWeb検索するコマンドです。
(が、まだまだ改善の余地がある筈なのでよろしければコメントを付けていただくなり、回答を編集するなりお願いします)
なお、`xdg-open`がなかったり別の検索エンジンを使いたいという場合は、お使いの環境に合わせて適宜書き換えてください。

```
command MesToClipboard let @+ = execute("1messages")

command! MesDeSearch call system("xdg-open \"https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=" .. execute("1messages") .. "\"")
```